# Get all DataPoints within a 'rubber-band' rectangle in a Chart control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I have an X-Y plot in a .NET 4.0 WinForms chart control. I am trying to implement rubber-band selection, so that the user could click and drag the mouse to create a rectangle on the plot, thus selecting all the points that lie within this rectangle.

While I was able to code up the drawing of the rectangle, I am now trying to identify the Datapoints that lie within this rectangle. Here is the relevant code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Drawing.Point _fromPosition;
    Rectangle _selectionRectangle;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // As the mouse moves, update the dimensions of the rectangle
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point p = e.Location;
            int x = Math.Min(_fromPosition.X, p.X);
            int y = Math.Min(_fromPosition.Y, p.Y);
            int w = Math.Abs(p.X - _fromPosition.X);
            int h = Math.Abs(p.Y - _fromPosition.Y);
            _selectionRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

            // Reset Data Point Attributes
            foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series[0].Points)
            {
                point.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Black;
                point.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None;
                point.BorderWidth = 1;
            }   
            this.Invalidate();
        }                     
    }

    private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is the starting position of the rectangle
        _fromPosition = e.Location;
    }

    private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2), _selectionRectangle);
        foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series[0].Points)
        {                
            // Check if the data point lies within the rectangle 
            if (_selectionRectangle.Contains(???))))
            {
                // How do I convert DataPoint into Point?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is query each DataPoint in the series and check if it lies within the Rectangle. Here, I am unable to transform each DataPoint into its corresponding Point. It seems pretty straightforward, so I am either missing something basic here or approaching the problem incorrectly.

I should also add that I referred to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065162/filled-rubber-band-in-winforms-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692065/microsoft-net-chart-control-select-points-using-rectangle), but they do not talk about how to actually identify DataPoints within the rectangle.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shown how to cheat the `Chart` into helping to get at the coordinates of `DataPoints` in the `Paint` event [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247240/get-coordinates-of-a-drawing-point-from-chart-values-in-textboxes/30248038#30248038).

But as you want to pick them up in the `Paint` event anyway, no cheating is needed..:

I define a List to collect the lassoed `DataPoints`:

```
List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
```

And I clear it on each new selection:

```
void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _fromPosition = e.Location;
    dataPoints.Clear();
}
```

At the end I can write out the results:

```
void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataPoint pt in dataPoints)
        Console.WriteLine("found:" + pt.ToString() +
            " at " + chart1.Series[0].Points.IndexOf(pt));
}
```

And in the `Paint` event we make use of the `ValueToPixelPosition` method of the two axes:

```
void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2) // dispose of my Pen
          {DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot})
       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _selectionRectangle);
    foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series[0].Points)
    {   // !! officially these functions are only reliable in a paint event!!
        double x = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(point.XValue);
        double y = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(point.YValues[0]);
        PointF pt = new PointF((float)x,(float)y);

        // Check if the data point lies within the rectangle 
        if (_selectionRectangle.Contains(Point.Round(pt)))
        {
            if (!dataPoints.Contains(point)) dataPoints.Add(point);
        }
    }      
}
```